# Passing Firebase Auth Token via SSL to App server

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I have some rather heavy/complicated logic that needs to reside on an app server.

The client would request the app server to perform some tasks on firebase data.

Is it safe to pass the user.firebaseauthToken via SSL (in a POST, not url encode) to the app server, where the server could simply use the token for authentication?

Comment: Why not just use a Firebase Secret on the server side?

Comment: Mike, if I use firebase secret on server side, I'd need to implement some sort of authentication between client and web API?  

Where as I just want the mobile client to tell the web server to perform a task.  If the client pass in an incorrect key, the web service just wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Auth Token you get from Firebase Simple Login is already being passed over SSL from Firebase to your client - so for you to pass it to your app server over SSL really isn't any different.

One thing you might also consider is eliminating the need to POST anything to your app server. You can setup a worker node that takes advantage of Firebase's real-time data sync to listen for changes to your user's data, and execute whatever processing it needs to when it detects a certain change/state.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks again for the help.


As for worker node, I was thinking that, but am concern if the worker is down for whatever reason when the data event occurred, it would not process certain tasks?

Or is there any queuing mechanism?

Comment: @jho - your web server could be down too, so you have the same potential issue there. You could mitigate that risk by pushing data onto a message queue (check out https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue for an implementation) and having multiple workers online (check out Heroku.com)

Comment: Thanks for the link

Yes, the web server can be done, but at least the client could keep retrying and know task is not being fulfilled.  My worry is that if the worker is down, then I'd have no idea which tasks have yet to be fulfilled.

Maybe I could have the client write a request objects into a firebase node, and have the server work off that?  let me check out this link to see how it is implemented.