# Securing RESTful API with Firebase OAuth?

Tags: api, rest, firebase, kong

I'm using Firebase in my iOS and web app to handle user authentication. I need to make sure a user is logged in before he can make any requests to my API. How would I accomplish such a thing with Firebase?

I'm thinking about using Kong - https://getkong.org - as a middleman for my API. Kong has a few options in relation to authenticating incoming requests - https://getkong.org/plugins. What would work with Firebase? JWT authentication? OAuth authentication? Key authentication?

Can you point me in the direction of a basic example? Or give me a basic overview of what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up authentication the users token server-side, like this:

https://gist.github.com/holgersindbaek/2cc55efd89517e21fbb52b4e95125003

Comment: Can you show in more detail how you made this work? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Firebase can allow you to require that a user be logged in with a third party service, such as Google or Facebook, before they can take certain data operations. There's fairly comprehensive documentation from Firebase themselves: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: I understand that. What I have is a RESTful API on the side, where I need to make sure that all incoming requests comes from a user that is already logged in through Firebase. And I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Makes sense?

Comment: Ah. Yes. There's a great suggestion on that over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060686/passing-firebase-auth-token-via-ssl-to-app-server

Essentially, instead of having the user communicate with your API directly, have the user insert something into Firebase which triggers the action on your server.

Comment: That's not going to work. When a user makes a request to the API, he needs a success or failure response back, like you normally get when you make a request to an API.

Comment: This is perhaps a little bit hacky, but you could have the client generate a nonce, insert it into Firebase, and then submit it along with their API request. You validate that the nonce exists in Firebase, and then respond appropriately.

Comment: That's an interesting way of going about it. It doesn't seem like the "right" way though. There's no way to use a OAuth authentication I already have in Firebase to authenticate with the API somehow?